# How to resolve error importing stats.scipy.loguniform

Tags: python, scipy, statistics

When importing 'loguniform' from scipy.stats i get an importerror.

Both in colab.google and jupyter.
I am running python 3.7.
scipy version 1.3.0
I even just upgraded to version 1.4.1, still the same error.

code:

```
from scipy.stats import loguniform
```

error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-b01b9ec1c262> in <module>
----> 1 from scipy.stats import loguniform

ImportError: cannot import name 'loguniform' from 'scipy.stats'
```

other distributions load just fine, 
`from scipy.stats import uniform`
no problem.

Comment: Double check that you have SciPy 1.4.0 installed: `import scipy; print(scipy.__version__); from scipy.stats import loguniform`

Answer (score 1):

For Python 3 SciPy version 1.4.0 or higher should allow you to install `loguniform`.

So, type `import scipy`, then type `print(scipy.__version__)` and make sure 1.4.0 or newer is installed, then type `from loguniform import scripy.stats`.

Answer (score -2):

You have the import backwards. You are importing scipy.stats from the library loguniform. 
Try:

```
from loguniform import scripy.stats
```

You can reference the Library description for more details on the uses of the library [Here](https://pypi.org/project/LogUniform/#description)

Comment: no, i am trying to load the loguniform dist from the scipy.stats library.
have a look at:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.loguniform.html#scipy.stats.loguniform

there is literally:

Examples

>>>
>>> from scipy.stats import loguniform
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)

From the examples section..
The import command should work